# Disable the system load while charging

Tags: power-supply, power

I have 5V charging a 3.7V lithium battery, when charging I would like to disconnect the load connected to the battery.

I'm trying to make this:
[image]

So far I got this:
[image]

If the connections made by the 5V power supply are not there the led is ON normally, but event turned if the power supply is turned OFF there is still no load. I think in my design I mix up some connections.

How to make this circuit?

Thanks

Comment: Normally the load is a microcontroller, in my circuit it's represented by the led. Yes it's to speed-up charging mainly.

Comment: The circuit looks nothing like the schematic. Try going over it again carefully and make sure your connections match the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit you have does not have the charging IC. You need a proper model for that. I am not addressing that problem here because your question is for the case when 5V supply is OFF, why the LED is OFF.

When the 5V supply is OFF, it is basically in high impedance. So, the voltage on the gate of the PMOS is set to 3V by the LI-ION cell. This switches OFF the PMOS and hence the LED is OFF. To fix this, you can add a diode from the 5V supply to the LI-ION cell as shown below so that the gate of the PMOS goes to 0V

[image]

Comment: I tried to add diode but on a wrong on (red wire on top), with your way it's working! I hope it won't affect the charging process. I will do more testing, so far look good. Thanks